# Retrieve/access dynamic variable from R function

Tags: r, function

I have a function in R that structures my raw data. I create a dataframe called `output` and then want to make a dynamic variable name depending on the function value `block`.

The output object does contain a dataframe as I want, and to rename it dynamically, at the end of the function I do this (within the function):

```
a = assign(paste("output", block, sep=""), output)
```

... but after running the function there is no object output1 (if `block` = 1). I simply cannot retrieve the output object, neither merely `output` nor the dynamic `output1` version.

I tried this then:

a = assign(paste("output", block, sep=""), output)
   return(a)

... but still - no success.
How can I retrieve the dynamic output variable? Where is my mistake?

Comment: Nearly impossible to say where the mistake is without a reproducible example, including the function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Environments.

`assign` will by default create a variable in the environment in which it's called. Read about environments here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

I assume you're doing something like:

```
foo <- function(x){ assign("b", x); b}
```

If you run `foo(5)`, you'll see it returns 5 as expected (implying that `b` was created successfully somewhere), but `b` won't exist in your current environment.

If, however, you do something like this

```
foo <- function(x){ assign("b", x, envir=parent.frame()); b}
```

Here, you're assigning not to the current environment at the time `assign` is called (which happens to be `foo`'s environment). Instead, you're assigning into the parent environment (which, since you're calling this function directly, will be your environment).

All this complexity should reveal to you that this will be fairly complex, a nightmare to maintain, and a really bad idea from a maintenance perspective. You'd surely be better off with something like:

```
foo <- function(x) { return(x) };
b <- foo(5)
```

Or if you need multiple items returned:

```
foo <- function(x) { return(list(df=data.frame(col1=x), b=x)) }
results <- foo(5)
df <- results$df
b <- results$b
```

But ours is not to reason why...

Comment: You could replace `parent.env(environment())` with `parent.frame()` for the cleaner semantics :)